# Would asking this question be permissible on the main site?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I have been working on a problem for days, that I previously mentioned on ComScience StackExchange. The answers were helpful. But, I need more information to develop a polynomial space algorithm.

> I would like to know if any researchers have found an efficient method
> to solve this problem.
>
> Given arbitrary integers, $M$ and $K$, is the sum of $2^K$+$M$ a
> prime?

I was told it was in $NP$ which means it is in $NPSPACE$. Since $PSPACE$=$NPSPACE$ a deterministic polynomial space algorithm exists for this problem.

It would be mathematically interesting to see how you would circumvent calculating $2^k$ because the value $2^k$ has $2^n$ bits and digits. So something fancy must be done to circumvent that problem.

### Question

I am just an amateur seeking a real mathematician's opinion and advice into what areas of research I should look into for developing this algorithm. Perhaps seeking references or papers into what I have found could turn out to be useful. May, I ask on the main site?

Comment: Perhaps consider asking at [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Before you ask this here, it would be helpful to motivate the desire for a PSPACE algorithm.  In particular, it is hard to imagine how compressible large factors would be.  Do you need to know the prime factors if there are any?  This would fly better on MathOverflow as a reference request for PSPACE algorithms in computational number theory. Before you ask that version, do a web search and see what you can find on your own, and then ask if such references you found would be worth reading for this problem.  Gerhard "Trying To Save Some Space" Paseman, 2020.07.21.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman nice one with that signature ;-)

Comment: "the value $2^k$ has $2^n$ bits and digits." Not following. What's $n$? $2^k$ has $k+1$ bits, and roughly $(0.3)k$ digits.

Comment: Do you have a reason why this problem would be in NP?

Comment: @GerryMyerson In computer Science we go by the input length. Consider the powers of 2 have EXACTLY value N 0-bits. Consider reducing binary subset sum into 0-bit Tally SubsetSum.  Tally Subset Sum is in P. The reduction is exponential otherwise P=NP.

Comment: @S.Carnahan I was told the execution paths can be used as a certificate for proving it is in NP.

Comment: "In computer Science we go by the input length." The input length of $2^k$ is $k+1$. "Consider the powers of 2 have EXACTLY value N 0-bits." Every single power of two has the same number of 0-bits, namely, $N$? I asked you "What's $n$," and instead of answering me you introduce "$N$" with no explanation. In "computer Science", you go by input length; in Mathematics, we go by defining our terms, and making sense.

Comment: @GerryMyerson "N" is exactly "K". It is the value used in exponentiation.

Comment: Good. The input length of $2^N$ is $N+1$. The input length of $2^K$ is $K+1$. And the input length of $2^k$ is $k+1$. That should cover all the bases. Do you still stand by "the value $2^k$ has $2^n$ bits and digits"?

Comment: @Gerry, if n is log k,  I stand by it. The issue of course is that the length of the number to be tested is exponential in the lengths of the input, but compactly expressible. One wonders if the computation for resolving primality is also compactly expressible.  Gerhard "Otherwise Let's Just Do EXPSPACE" Paseman, 2020.07.22.

Comment: @Gerhard sure, but OP has given no indication that $n$ is $\log k$, indeed OP has written "$N$ is exactly $K$." Also, I'm not sure what you mean by the *length* of a number. The *number* is exponential in the length of the input, but what is the length of the number?

Comment: The OP has given no indication that he (pronoun presumption) knows the notation or the conventions here in MathOverflow, and seems to be using an unstated convention from computer science.  You can try to force him to follow the convention of this forum through your commenting style, or you can say something like "What you say does not make sense to me unless n is log k. Even then more exposition is needed. In this forum we need things to be more clear and explicit." Gerhard "These Times Affect Us All" Paseman, 2020.07.22.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I meant when in the binary length the value $2^K$ is exponential.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Perhaps a previous question of mine on stackexchange math may help clarify. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3563682/is-the-powers-of-base-2-always-exponential-in-the-number-of-digits

Comment: @TravisWells why do you have $K$ and $n$ and $k$—are these all potentially different numbers? What is the definition of the numbers $n$ and $k$, in terms of the given $M$ and $K$? The question as it stands is definitely not suitable for the main site because you haven't defined or unambiguously described half the variables you have introduced.

Comment: The value $2^K$ is exponential – no disagreement from me on that, Travis. But the *input* for $2^K$ has length $K+1$, which is not exponential.

Comment: @Gerhard I'm glad that your commenting style has elicited the response, "in the binary length the value $2^K$ is exponential." I hope you will continue to extract more exposition, clarity, and explicitness from OP.

Comment: I note that the m.se question to which OP links was closed by the voters there because it was not at all clear what OP was asking. How is an unclear question there going to clarify an unclear question here?

Comment: @GerryMyerson As an example that $K$+$1$ is exponential, Convert a integer Subset Sum instance into tallies. S = $1,2,3,4$. $Target$ = $7$.  $S$ = 1,11,111,1111, Target = 1111111. As you can see, it is easy to be fooled that was a polynomial reduction. It is not, because the reduction is exponential. It takes $2^n$ space and time to reduce Integer Subset Sum into Tally Subset-Sum (which is in $P$). The amount of tallies are polynomial in the magnitude of the integers, but not the length.

Comment: Let me try another approach. You've said nothing about any actual primality-testing algorithm. Your whole question is based on the problem of calculating $2^k$. So, doesn't your argument suggest that multiplying two numbers of the form $2^k+m$ can't be done in polynomial space? Or dividing $2^k+m$ by three? The way I see it: if your argument really suggests you can't multiply, or divide by three, in polynomial space, then it shows that you don't understand what polynomial space is. And if it doesn't show that you can't do those things in polynomial space, then (continued)

Comment: (continued) then it behooves you to explain what part of your argument applies to primality-testing but not to multiplication and not to division by three, because you haven't used any facts about primality-testing in your question.

Comment: @Gerry  Arbitary integers are M and K. Ther is nothing mor specific too it.  The solution is exponetial in the worst case in digit and/or bitlength.

Comment: You are referring to multiplication, Travis? So multiplication takes exponential space?

Comment: This is only tangential but you can write `$2^K+M$` to get $2^K+M$. You don't need to split the formula as `$2^K$+$M$` $2^K$+$M$. (Notice that + looks differently and has different spacing.)

Comment: @GerryMyerson Exponentiation takes exponential space in the digit length and binary length. When the inputs are integers. Multiplication takes polynomial space when in binary and/or integers as inputs.